# How do I remove several duplicate geometries?

Tags: postgresql, duplicates, postgis

Several of the same geometries appears in the database. I an output with only one object_id for every distinct geometry.

I have managed to get a result with two overlapping geometries.

```sql
SELECT
  a.objekt_id,
  b.objekt_id,
  a.geometri
  b.geometri
from
  plandk.theme_pdk_tilslutningspligtomraade_vedtaget_v a,
  plandk.theme_pdk_tilslutningspligtomraade_vedtaget_v b
WHERE 
  ST_EQUALS(a.geometri, b.geometri)
AND
  a.objekt_id != b.objekt_id;
```

The result is a table showing a row for two overlapping geometries. Though sometimes there are three rows with six overlapping geometries. I want the result to have all these in one row.

Comment: Use `a.objekt_id < b.objekt_id`, and you are down to three.

Answer (score 1):

```
DELETE FROM plandk.theme_pdk_tilslutningspligtomraade_vedtaget_v t
 WHERE EXISTS (SELECT FROM plandk.theme_pdk_tilslutningspligtomraade_vedtaget_v t2
                WHERE t.objekt_id > t2.objekt_id
                  AND ST_EQUALS(a.geometri, b.geometri))
```

It will delete all doubled geometries except this with lowest id for each equal geometry group.

Comment: Before deleting something just change delete from "Select *" to check if this is it you want to delete ;)